# Media component stays always over modal

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, media

I'm using p:dialog with modal=true and p:media in one single page.
Having Problems with Internet Explorer like:

First fill the media component and after click in one button for show the modal -> problem the media component stays always over modal (this is the problem)

I use Primefaces 5.1.

Comment: What if you add `appendTo="@(body)"` to your p:dialog?

Comment: the dialog already have appendTo="@(body)"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem using the documentviewer from primefaces extensions instead media from primefaces.

Using this:

```
<pe:documentViewer locale="pt" height="#{previewHeight}" value="#{previewComponent.file}">
                        #{text['error.documentviewer']}
</pe:documentViewer>
```

instead this:

```
<p:media value="#{previewComponent.file}" height="#{previewHeight}" width="100%" player="pdf" cache="false">
                        #{text['error.documentviewer']}
</p:media>
```